# Import CSV File Into MySQL Table

Tags: java, mysql, csv, opencsv

I have those line in CSV file and i wanna import those column into database

```
Notification Identifier / State / Severity / Event Time / Probable Cause / Managed Object / Alarm Type / Additional Text 
ALARM /  1347413987 /  Outstanding /  Critical /  Thu, Feb 18, 2016 04:50:22 PM /  NeighborDown /  5620SAM tunisiana_ns:.network.ne.5620SAM6_1 SERVICE 
service-652:192.168.161.36:routingInstance:ospf-v2:areaSite-0.0.0.0:interface-2 /  EquipmentAlarm / "PE9036
```

Every Line  begin with this "ALARM" and my separator is "/"
Please help me to import this data to a MySQL DB.

Comment: I don't know where Java comes into play, but I don't think you even need it.  Try using `LOAD DATA` (you can Google this).

Comment: i wannt make it in java code you know i try different methode ans i didn't get it even with google so please can u help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for LOAD DATA INFILE here.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

You can use csv friendly characters in

```
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

Also there are certail GUI tools like [SQLyog](http://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/217-import-csv-data-using-load-local), which give a direct and an easy way to import CSV files partly or completely into your table on the server.

Comment: I want to use separated "/" and begin line with "alarm" but when i run this query i got error

Comment: did you put alarm in the character  for STARTING BY ' '? What error did you get?

Comment: query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE +path+ INTO TABLE alarm FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/'  STARTING BY 'alarm'";

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+  STARTING BY 'alarm'' at line 1

Comment: hope you are not making the mistake of enclosing "ALARM" in mismatched characters like ' " or " '". Because that is what you have pasted here

Comment: i try this too but it doesn't work for me query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE +path+ INTO TABLE alarm FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/'  STARTING BY ' ALARM ' ";

Comment: and i wannt to make a loop to insert all the ligne

Comment: now i got this problem ==>Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Answer (score 0):

As they suggest in the comments a better way is:

```
String esquel = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path +
                "' INTO TABLE tableName " +
                " FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'/\' +
                " LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'";
```

Comment: The '+' concatenates all the string, so if you print or debug that variable it should be something like this: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\alarm.csv' INTO TABLE alarm FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/' `

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is to use a library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

i have on Error :

```
ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+' at line 1
```

and this is the query:

```
 query = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + "D:\\alarm.csv" + "' INTO TABLE alarm " +" FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'/\' + ";
```